# Sinon FakeXMLHttpRequest TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.requests[0]')

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, mocha.js, sinon

I've seen other questions on this but they don't seem to have come across the same problem.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
  var requests = this.requests = [];

  this.xhr.onCreate = function (xhr) {
    requests.push(xhr);
  }.bind(this);
});

afterEach(function() {
  this.xhr.restore();
});

this.requests[0].respond(500, { 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
'[{ "Response": "500 error text", "ResponseText": "This was the first thing we expected to happen"}]');
```

This seems to match what is in the documentation for sinon when using FakeXMLHttpRequest but it always returns an error stating

*TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.requests[0]')*

I can't see why though, I don't think it does not appear to be missing anything vital compared to all the examples I have seen.

Comment: is sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest supposed to be signon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I don't think so. The Sinon documenation has it as 'sinon'
http://sinonjs.org/docs/#useFakeXMLHttpRequest

Comment: Oh I didn't know what that was, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been making any requests ... That's why the list of requests is empty.